# Random number generation problem with meta table

Tags: random, lua, metatable

Please look at the next code, Lua.

```
randomNumber = {
  new = function(self,o)
  o = o or {}
  setmetatable(o, self)
  self.__index = self
  return o
  end,

  math.randomseed(os.time()),
  
  getNum = math.random()
}

for i = 1, 10 do
  x = randomNumber:new()
  print(x.getNum)
end
```

The output results are as follows.

```
0.13782639400248
0.13782639400248
0.13782639400248
0.13782639400248
0.13782639400248
0.13782639400248
0.13782639400248
0.13782639400248
0.13782639400248
0.13782639400248
```

I want to get 10 different numbers. Can someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `math.randomseed(os.time())` should occur at the beginning of the script only.

Comment: ok. thank you. But the result doesn't change.

Comment: Replace `getNum = math.random()` with `getNum = math.random` and `print(x.getNum)` with `print(x.getNum())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at your table constructor

```
randomNumber = {
  new = function(self,o)  -- this assigns a function to randomNumber["new"]
  o = o or {}             -- that will return a new instance of your class
  setmetatable(o, self)
  self.__index = self
  return o
  end,

  math.randomseed(os.time()), -- this assigns the first of two random seed components
                              -- returned by math.randomseed to randomNumber[1]
  
  getNum = math.random()    -- this assings a random number [0,1) to randomNumber["getNum"]
}
```

In the loop

```
for i = 1, 10 do
  x = randomNumber:new()
  print(x.getNum)
end
```

You create a new instance named `x` of `randomNumber` 10 times.
You then print `x.getNum`.

`x.getNum` is a nil value so Lua will check wether `x` has a metatable with a `__index` field. `__index` refers to `randomNumber` so Lua will print `randomNumber.getNum` which is the random number `[0,1)` which has not changed since we constructed `randomNumber`.

You need to call `math.random` every time you want a new random number.

If you want each instance of `randomNumber` to be constructed with a random number you need to assign `o.rn = math.random()` in your `new` function and either access it via `x.rn` later or add a function `getNum` to `randomNumber`.

```
getNum = function (self) return self.rn end`
```

so you can `print(x:getNum())`

I'm not sure if this is more than a exercise with metatables. But having a dedicated class that just holds a single number doesn't make too much sense to me. Just use a number value.

Comment: Your answer was helpful enough for me. Thank you so much~

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is simply...

In a very fast Lua loop `os.time()` is not fast enough to set a good random seed.

You have to use something that is faster, like...

```
-- Lua 5.3 - 5.4
for i = 1, 10 do
 math.randomseed(math.random(math.mininteger, math.maxinteger)) -- Set seed before print()
 print('Seed: ' .. math.randomseed(math.random(math.mininteger, math.maxinteger)), '\nRandom: ' .. math.random(math.maxinteger)) -- Set seed in print()
 math.randomseed(math.random(math.mininteger, math.maxinteger)) -- Set seed after print()
end
```

That puts out something like...

```
Seed: -634325252416746990   
Random: 5554602367968798340
Seed: 574322306421972413    
Random: 3317370212892010822
Seed: -5465512503977683870  
Random: 6616070635043877067
Seed: -2566820481734265082  
Random: 2581377472505137533
Seed: -8408106760854456996  
Random: 708876515734960246
Seed: 5641371185711405705   
Random: 4259990225803106481
Seed: -3172432877848732304  
Random: 5472223279668970440
Seed: 5842301042132325387   
Random: 6912957407189525897
Seed: 2126448976574029213   
Random: 6156943198274398962
Seed: 4832369017575479065   
Random: 6054703131408226582
```

Lua 5.1

```
-- Lua 5.1
math.randomseed(math.random(os.time()))

for i = 1, 10 do
 math.randomseed(math.random(-99999999, 999999999)) -- Set seed before print()
 print('Random: ' .. tostring(math.random(-999999999, 999999999)))                       
 math.randomseed(math.random(-999999999, 999999999)) -- Set seed after print()
end
```